# How to control left and right volume of my headphone in kubuntu seperately?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu

[image]

This is gui tool available in windows 7

Any similar gui tool available in kubuntu?                                                                                      .

Comment: You mean control the volume of right and left separately?

Comment: @Zacharee1 yes thats what i mean

Comment: That would be awesome. I used Kubuntu for 3 years, but never asked about such option. Recently, I found that Alsa can use a equalizer. Also pulseaudio can, but I have not tested it yet. I don't remember, but Alsamixer allow to do many things, maybe it can control separated chanels. Best regards!

Comment: well reason i need this is - some jacka** sold me a head phone with great sound but there is a problem that sound is a little louder in left than right. It can be noticed if i listen carefully else its fine

Comment: @GTRONICK You can do so using Kmix.

Comment: Wow I didn't remember that kmix can do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes,** KDE has such an application. It's `kmix`.

1. Install it with

   ```
   sudo apt install kmix
   ```
2. Open it from Menu.
3. Go to **Playback Devices** tab
4. Right click on the volume slider
5. Select from the popup-menu **Split Channels**
6. Apply your preferred settings.

   [image: kmix dual channel slider]